# Installing python mac 2.7.6

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I would like to have a local install of python in my mac for an older version of python. For instance I have python 2.7.10. However I would like python 2.7.6 for a particular project development. How can I install 2.7.6, without impacting mac's default python or previously installed versions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: There shouldn't be any significant difference between 2.7.6 and 2.7.10, apart from bug fixes. Why do you need those two versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts] to install multiple versions of Python on the same machine without necesarrily overriding the default Python interpreter (https://www.macports.org/) (based on my personal experience I recommend Homebrew).

Have a look at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/#doing-it-right.

Edit: I checked for Python and it's not among the standard old repositories like `homebrew/versions` or `homebrew/boneyard` so you have to install it directly from github by searching for the formualr with `2.7.6` version which is this one:

https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/blob/72eb84e61e46f9c22193b7b0fbcf60993b795c8e/Library/Formula/python.rb

Brew can install it right from github:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/72eb84e61e46f9c22193b7b0fbcf60993b795c8e/Library/Formula/python.rb
```

Comment: How do I specify a particular version - 2.7.6 using brew? Furthermore I would like this install not to impact already installed versions of python

Comment: I updated my answer. If you already have `python` installed via `brew` you'd just have to unlink it with `brew unlink python` which only removes symlinks but keeps all binaries (eg. on my system in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python). You can also install python with `brew`, right after that unlink it and call it only via its full path.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about using [virtualenvs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). A Virtual Environment is a tool to keep the dependencies required by different projects in separate places, by creating virtual Python environments for them. It solves the “Project X depends on version 1.x but, Project Y needs 4.x” dilemma, and keeps your global site-packages directory clean and manageable.

[Here](https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) You have a good tutorial for Mac OS, it's written for Yosemite but should work on other os versions too.

As mentioned in this question: [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv), You can use `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>` command to specify the Python version for virtualenv.